# Python sockets and end loop

Tags: python, c#, loops, sockets

I'm working on a project that uses sockets for communication. What I want is to create a loop that sending data continiously, but when I send a message 'stop' , loop needs to be stopped. I have issue about, when loop starts, the new message is not received.

I got 2 buttons on my form. Start and Stop. First I click button 1 and loop starts but when buttons is clicked, nothing happens.

Basically the codes that I write. I have no ethernet on pc so I write on phone. Sorry.

python

```
def loop:
     while stus:
             socket.sendall(data) 
#in main
stus = True
while true:
         str = socket.recv(1024)
         if str == "startloop":
               loop()
         elif str = "stoploop"
                 stus=False
```

c#

```
//But1
socket.send("startloop") 

//But2
socket.send("stoploop")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "startloop" message sends your code into `loop()` which runs until infinity. Therefore the application will never read the "stoploop" message. If you want your code to do 2 things at the same time (keep sending data + check for stop message) then you either have to:

1. Start a backgroundthread to keep sending the data, and make sure to exit that thread when you receive stoploop.
2. Move socket.sendall into main while loop, make your socket calls non-blocking (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)), then if the socket.recv raises socket.timeout (because there was no data) you can call socket.sendall

Option 2 would look something like this;

```py
socket.setnonblocking()
started = False
while True:
  try:
    message = socket.recv(1024)
  except socket.timeout:
    if started:
      socket.sendall(data)
  else:
    if message == 'startloop':
      started = True
    if message == 'stoploop':
      break
```

But you might want to consider to set a timeout to avoid having 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the name of the variables. `str` is a keyword and the output of `str == startloop` or `str == stoploop` will always be `False` because `str` class is not equals to the string `startloop`.
Try to change the name, for example in `str_test` .

Also make sure to use the `break` or `continue` if you want to stop or continue the execution respectively.

```
def loop():
         while stus:
                 socket.sendall(data) 
#in main
while true:
     str_test = socket.recv(1024)
     if str_test == "startloop":
         loop()
     elif str_test = "stoploop"
         break
```